# C++ ? operator with continue operator in for loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, continue

I have a method which looks like this:

```
bool Perfect(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        num%i == 0 ? sum += i : continue;
    }
    return sum == num ? true : false;
}
```

I'm trying to combine here ? operator with continue operator...

So logically if the statement here is false in this line:

```
num%i == 0 ? sum += i : continue;
```

I will just skip the iteration or do nothing?

If I do it like this the compiler reports an error like:

```
expected an expression
```

And in case like this:

```
num%i == 0 ? sum += i
```

It says:

```
Expected a ':'
```

Is there any way to use continue with ? operator or just simply avoid false case somehow ???

Comment: Don't force use of a ternary in a case like this; it doesn't make any sense. Just use if/else. Also, `return sum == num ? true : false;` should just be written as `return sum == num`;

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm just exploring the possibilities of c++ , which is why I'm curious if there's a solution to use ternary operator with these kinds of cases :)

Comment: Ternarys are used to conditionally return a value. `continue` doesn't evaluate to anything useful. Experimenting is good, but so is recognizing the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Having `continue` at the end of the for-loop is especially useless, as the loop will continue anyway. And the ternary operator has very little practical use, so please focus on something more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool Perfect(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        if(num % i == 0)
         sum += i;
    }
    return sum == num;
}
```

Use an `if` statement. No need of `continue` since you have no other statement after `sum += i`.

Comment: just use `return sum == num;`

Answer (score 3):

C++ and C have both *statements* and *expressions* (notice that an assignment or a function call is an expression, and that expressions are statements). They are different syntactic (and semantical) things.

You could have coded (but this is weird style as a statement reduced to a `?:` conditional expression) inside your `for` loop:

```
(num%i == 0) ? (sum += i) : 0;
```

<sup>(when `num%i`  is non-zero, that evaluates to `0` which has no significant side effect; BTW that last occurrence of `0`  could be `1234` or any constant integral expression)</sup>

Some programming languages (notably Scheme, read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)) have only expressions (and no statements).

The ternary [`?:` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) applies to expressions and gives an expression (so can't be used for statements).

Conditional statements use the `if`  keyword. In your case it is much more readable (because you are using `sum += i` only for its side effect) and an `if` statement is here easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a ternary operator in this way. You would normally use it for assigning a value to a variable based on an expression being true or false. Eg.

```
int j, i,

j = (i == 2) ? 5: 10;
```

If i is equal to 2 then j is given the value of 5 else if i is not equal to 2 then j is given the value of 10.